# React + Grails, very simple setup but won't render

Tags: grails, reactjs

I'm following a course on Udemy demonstrating a very simple 'hello world'-setup with React (code below). However, when I use this code in a .gsp file in my grails app, it fails to render. The chrome debugger doesn't show any errors either. Any thoughts?

```
<head>
  <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.13.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>

<script type="text/jsx">
  // Define a `class`
  var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return <div>
        Hello World!
      </div>
    }
  });

  // React, please render this class
  var element = React.createElement(HelloWorld);

  // React, after you render this class, please place it in my body tag
  React.render(element, document.body);
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `<g:javascript>...</g:javascript>` ?

Answer (score 0):

It works when I put my script tag in the header, apparently you can't put it below the body.